# How to make the last added item to a checkedlistbox automatically selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using winforms and i'm pretty new to it,

can any one help me with:

How to make the last added item to a checkedlistbox automatically selected?

Every new item I add to the checkedlistbox, i want it to be selected.

Thank you!

Nadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, add this line after you add an item:

```
checkedlistbox1.SelectedIndex = checkedlistbox1.Items.Count-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do a number of things:

1) Set the checked state of the item when you add it to the CheckedListBox manually.

```
CheckedListBoxItem cbl = new CheckedListBoxItem ();
this.checkListBox.Items.Add(cbl);
clb.Checked = true;
```

2) Create a sub-class of the CheckedListBox and override the 'Add' method to check the item just before adding it.

3) Create a sub-class of the CheckedListBox that exposes an ItemAdded event, wire up to that event and then set the checked state of the item.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>work with `ControlAdded` event of your checkedListBox</strike>  and use `Items.count-1` to get the last item added.

Comment: That event does not work for items being added. In fact there is no 'ItemsAdded' event for a ListBox.